# Vuejs router.params undefined

Tags: vue-router, vue.js

I am just trying a basic functionality with router params and I am getting undefined for router.params

my template

```
 <div id="app><template id="image-capture">
          <div class="row" >
               <router-link :to="{ path: 'vc/'+item.id}" class="btn btn-primary"> ACCEPT</router-link>
    </div>
      </template></div>
```

now my url looks like this http://localhost/cams-web/#/vc/3

```
const ic = {
  template: '#image-capture' ,
}

const vc = {
  template: '#video-capture' ,

  mounted () {
    this.init()
  },

  methods: {
    init () {
    console.log(router);  //returns object
 console.log(router.params); //undefined.. 
   },
    }
}


const routes = [
  { path: '/ic', component:   ic},
  { path: '/vc/:id', component:  vc}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
})

 new Vue({
  router,
   }).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To access the [router params](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), you need to use `this.$route.params` in your code. Your code should be something like following:

```
const vc = {
  template: '#video-capture' ,

  mounted () {
    this.init()
  },

  methods: {
    init () {
      console.log(this.$route);  //should return object
      console.log(this.$route.params); //should return object 
      console.log(this.$route.params.id); //should return id of URL param 
    },
  }
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cyyx612/).

Comment: ha..thanks so much... I was trying "this.route"..when $route was undefined never got a clue to this.$route..

Comment: Thanks, I was attempting to access this.$router which returns a different object.